# Cannot build Firebase on iOS from Xcode but Android works well + authorization

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

We have created a Firebase application on Android and the Firebase setup worked well on Android, easy-peasy and we have followed directions regarding the iOS setup with Unity and had multiple problems. My developers have been looking for a solution for 3 days and tried dosens of things but to no avail.

Unity is building ok, but upon transfering to Xcode there is a problem (pasting below). We tried different version of Unity, different versions of Xcode, different NET framework and we managed to build the app but upon logging nothing was happening. Some authorisation problem. We implemented a QR code reader and manual entry of information to login and nothing is happening in both cases, there is no authorisation, and most of the time we could not even build.

Right now, my dev has texted me that he thinks that this is closest to what we have been experiencing although not precisely this -> [Firebase Unity iOS Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108793/firebase-unity-ios-problems)

Below I am pasting the error from Xcode:

> 2018-11-05 16:03:49.987060+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96165]
>   [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful 2018-11-05
>   16:03:50.051957+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96161]  -
>   [I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled.
>   Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen
>   name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen
>   reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean)
>   in the Info.plist 2018-11-05 16:03:50.097906+0100
>   dzienstrategii[628:96003] Built from '2018.2/release' branch, Version
>   '2018.2.14f1 (3262fb3b0716)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend
>   'il2cpp' 2018-11-05 16:03:50.101126+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] ->
>   registered mono modules 0x106419480
>   -> applicationDidFinishLaunching() 2018-11-05 16:03:50.195222+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled 2018-11-05
>   16:03:50.195802+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] Metal API Validation
>   Disabled 2018-11-05 16:03:50.469600+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003]
>   [Warning] Trying to set delaysTouchesBegan to NO on a system gate
>   gesture recognizer - this is unsupported and will have undesired side
>   effects
>   -> applicationDidBecomeActive() GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1 Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A10 GPU Initialize
>   engine version: 2018.2.14f1 (3262fb3b0716) FMOD failed to initialize
>   the output device.: "Error initializing output device. " (60)
>
> (Filename:  Line: 1417) Forced to initialize FMOD to to the device
>   driver's system output rate 48000, this may impact performance and/or
>   give inconsistent experiences compared to selected sample rate 24000
>
> (Filename:  Line: 1356) FMOD failed to initialize the output device.:
>   "Error initializing output device. " (60)
>
> (Filename:  Line: 1417) FMOD failed to initialize any audio devices,
>   running on emulated software output with no sound. Please check your
>   audio drivers and/or hardware for malfunction. UnloadTime: 0.451125 ms
>   Loading c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43) Unloading 4 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now
>   loaded: 0) Loading c__Iterator0:MoveNext()
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43)
>   -> applicationWillResignActive() UnloadTime: 1.163708 ms 2018-11-05 16:03:54.829080+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] ERROR: Unable to
>   configure Firebase services: Google Analytics for Firebase version
>   (50200000) does not match with Google App Measurement (50300000)
>   version. Please update. Unable to configure Firebase services: Google
>   Analytics for Firebase version (50200000) does not match with Google
>   App Measurement (50300000) version. Please update.
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal()
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate, FirebaseApp)
>   Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth:get_DefaultInstance() Authorization:Awake()
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43) InitializationException:  Firebase app creation failed.   at
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.CreateDelegate
>   createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Authorization.Awake () [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1) 2018-11-05
>   16:03:54.829969+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] Default app is already
>   present, deleting the existing default app and recreating Default app
>   is already present, deleting the existing default app and recreating
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal()
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate, FirebaseApp)
>   Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase:get_DefaultInstance()
>   Database:Awake()
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43) 2018-11-05 16:03:54.830143+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003]
>   ERROR: Failed to delete existing default app Failed to delete existing
>   default app Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateInternal()
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp:CreateAndTrack(CreateDelegate, FirebaseApp)
>   Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase:get_DefaultInstance()
>   Database:Awake()
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43) 2018-11-05 16:03:54.831241+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96161]
>   5.9.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000007] App does not exist. 2018-11-05 16:03:54.831756+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] ERROR:
>   Database::GetInstance(https://gpec-dzien-strategii.firebaseio.com/):
>   nil FIRApp instance passed to databaseForApp.
>   Database::GetInstance(https://gpec-dzien-strategii.firebaseio.com/):
>   nil FIRApp instance passed to databaseForApp.
>   Firebase.Database.Internal.InternalFirebaseDatabase:GetInstance(FirebaseApp,
>   String) Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase:GetInstance(FirebaseApp,
>   String) Database:Awake()
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43) DatabaseException: Failed to get FirebaseDatabase instance.
>   Please check the log for more information.   at
>   Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance (Firebase.FirebaseApp
>   app, System.String url) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Database.Awake () [0x00000] in :0
>
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
>   InvalidOperationException: Don't call Firebase functions before
>   CheckDependencies has finished   at
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp.ThrowIfCheckDependenciesRunning () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Firebase.FirebaseApp.GetInstance
>   (System.String name) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Firebase.FirebaseApp.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in :0    at Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.get_DefaultInstance
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at FileDownloader.Awake ()
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
>
> Unloading 5 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now:
>   1982. Total: 1.889291 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.589958 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.043291 ms MarkObjects: 1.231791 ms 
>   DeleteObjects: 0.023750 ms) 2018-11-05 16:03:54.840768+0100
>   dzienstrategii[628:96003] [MC] System group container for
>   systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is
>   /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2018-11-05 16:03:54.841033+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] [MC] Reading
>   from public effective user settings. 2018-11-05 16:03:55.075118+0100
>   dzienstrategii[628:96003] Current EasyWebCam Pixel Format is BGRA
>   2018-11-05 16:03:55.078916+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96003] supported
>   capture preset AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480. An abnormal situation
>   has occurred: the PlayerLoop internal function has been called
>   recursively. Please contact Customer Support with a sample project so
>   that we can reproduce the problem and troubleshoot it.
>   DeviceCamera:Play() [ line 385]  (Filename:  Line: 385)
>   NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object
>   instance was required.   at Database.GetInitiatives () [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
>   -> applicationDidEnterBackground()
>   -> applicationWillEnterForeground() 2018-11-05 16:03:59.677588+0100 dzienstrategii[628:96161] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_error(1584) [C2.1:2][0x1096e6720] Lower protocol
>   stack error: 53 2018-11-05 16:03:59.677700+0100
>   dzienstrategii[628:96161] [BoringSSL]
>   nw_protocol_boringssl_error(1584) [C1.1:2][0x11175ef90] Lower protocol
>   stack error: 53
>   -> applicationDidBecomeActive() Email :xyz@gpec.pl QRScanner:UserScanFinished(String) QRCodeDecodeController:Update()
>
> (Filename:
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h
>   Line: 43) NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an
>   object instance was required.   at Authorization.LoginUser
>   (System.String email, System.String password) [0x00000] in :0    at QRCodeDecodeController.Update () [0x00000] in
>   :0
>
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)Z

Comment: Same here. Any update or solution?